# How do I get the text in this PDF book to be more clear?

Tags: pdf

I needed to download a pdf version of this book: http://www.earth.illinois.edu/sustain/sustainability_text.html but when I use Adobe Reader the text is super-faint and a pain to read on my computer.  What is causing it?  Is it the reader or my computer?  How can I fix it so I can read the textbook comfortably?

Win 7 Pro.

Comment: It looks like crap on my computer too.

Comment: It looks like it is is not the reader or the computer, but the display on both is just as bad.

Comment: @RoryAlsop: on both?

Comment: @verve - I meant to say: have tried it in foxit and adobe. both as bad as each other.

Answer (score 0):

The PDF uses PostScript Type 3 fonts, which PDF reader have problems rendering. You should contact the author and tell him to recreate the PDF with Type 1 fonts. If he has questions, point him to [tex.sx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) (since he uses [TeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX)).

Comment: What's TeX? And, it is the source that's the problem for sure?

Comment: @verve: [TeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX) is the software used to produce that PDF. The author uses wrong settings.